# How to configure interfaces to run a virtualised firewall on QEMU on a host with only one network interface?

Tags: networking, qemu, openwrt

I lease a virtual machine that hosts a website and some backends for my projects. I'd like to set up a VPN endpoint, preferably on OpenWRT or Mikrotik CHR, so I thought that using a VM and 'hiding' all backends behind a NAT would be a good idea.
Now here is the problem: how to configure VM so it would exclusively use host's network interface (with 'public' - now host's - IP address claimed by the OpenWRT VM) and have a second interface to access the host via virtualised LAN? So far I've only tried using QEMU's NAT-ed stack and confirmed that OpenWRT has an internet access through it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting up that virtual machine as a bastion node?
I am not sure I have correct understanding to this sentence.

> so it would exclusively use host's network interface (with 'public' - now host's - IP address claimed by the OpenWRT VM)

If your VM is something like AWS EC2, or similar, I think you could install a OpenVPN server and make sure that your VM has local access or with that subnet to your backend service.

You can then connect to that VPN server and route all your traffic to that subnet will work

Comment: Correct, you got that right. Now, running _virsh_ confirms I have an _internal_ network and an _external_ one, currently NAT-ed to WAN. I was trying to search on that, but I'm confused - one source claims I can't use WAN interface for the _external_ (meaning: the host won't have an IP address on this interface), the other one claims it is possible.
Edit: Oh, one more thing. SRV-IO is not on, neither is _nested virtualisation_, both won't be.